# WPF Popup behave like office floating toolbar

Tags: wpf, popup, tooltip, mouseover

I have an image control that shows a small thumbnail of an image,
I would like to have a popup control that pops when the mouse is over the thumbnail, and shows a big instance of the image
I would also like the popup to remain open as long as the mouse is over the popup or the thumbnail

I've tried it with "IsMouseOver" and the popup flickers every time he opens (and the mouse moves on it)

How can I get this behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want your `Popup` visible when the mouse is "either" over the `Image` or the actual `Popup` itself when it's open.

You could try something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
  <Setter Property="IsOpen"
          Value="True" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <!-- Switch "someImage" in the following line to your actual image element -->
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=someImage,
                                      Path=IsMouseOver}"
                    Value="False" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                      Path=IsMouseOver}"
                    Value="False" />
      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="IsOpen"
              Value="False" />
    </MultiDataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As for the flicker:

I'm assuming you either have the `Popup` positioned over the `Image` or have it where your mouse pointer currently is.

^^ If so this is going to put `IsOpen` in a loop of `True/False` with just a direct single binding to `Image.IsMouseOver`